# React router - click on card and redirect to a new page with content of that card (card details)

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of cards that shows movies/TV shows. What I need is when I click on a card, it redirects me to a new page (Details page) where I can see the details of that specific movie/card.

My card.js and card-collection.js are:

card :

```
import React from 'react';
import './card.styles.css';

const Card = ({ item }) => (
  <div className='card-container'>
    <div
      className='image'
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280${item.backdrop_path})`,
      }}
    ></div>
    <div className='basic-info'>
      {item.name ? (
        <p className='title'>{item.name}</p>
      ) : (
        <p className='title'>{item.title}</p>
      )}

      {item.first_air_date ? (
        <p className='title'> {item.first_air_date.substring(0, 4)}</p>
      ) : (
        <p className='title'>{item.release_date.substring(0, 4)} </p>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Card;
```

card-collection:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '../card/card.component';
import './card-collection.styles.css';

class CardCollection extends React.Component {
  goToDetails = (item) => {
    localStorage.setItem('selectedItem', item);
    this.props.history.push('/details');
  };

  render() {
    console.log('PROPOVI SUUU', this.props);
    return (
      <div className='card-collection'>
        {this.props.items.data
          .filter((item, idx) => idx < 10)
          .map((item) => (
            <Card
              key={item.id}
              item={item}
              onClick={() => this.goToDetails(item)}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardCollection;
```

Ive tried multiple things, but I cant seem to pass my card props (i can work with only the id if nothing else), but I couldnt send that info via  or anything else ive tried.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your Card component with Link tags with specified route.

`<Link to="details/${id}"> <Card props={props} /> </Link>`

[Docs react-router Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `onClick` event as a prop to the `Card` component. This will not capture the click event on the card item in the list. Try wrapping the `Card` component in an element that will capture the click. Something like this should work:

```
<div onClick={() => this.goToDetails(item)}>
    <Card key={item.id} item={item} />
</div>
```